...if $\mathfrak{a}\subset\cup_{i=1}^{s}\mathfrak{p_i}$, then $\mathfrak{a_1}\subset \mathfrak{p_i}$ for some $i$
The following is taken from the text An Introduction to Grobner Bases by: Ralf Froberg
Background
Definition 63 (Prime Ideal).:  An ideal $\mathfrak{p}\neq R$ in  a ring $R$ is a prime ideal if $rs\in \mathfrak{p}$ implies $r\in \mathfrak{p}$ or $s\in \mathfrak{p}$.
Lemma  65: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal and let $\mathfrak{p_i}$ be prime ideals for $i=1,\ldots,s$. if $\mathfrak{a}\subset\cup_{i=1}^{s}\mathfrak{p_i}$, then $\mathfrak{a_1}\subset \mathfrak{p_i}$ for some $i$.

Proof.  We use induction over $s$.  If $s=2$ and $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq\mathfrak{p_1}\cup\mathfrak{p_2},\mathfrak{a}\nsubseteq\mathfrak{p_1},\mathfrak{a}\nsubseteq\mathfrak{p_2}$ there exists $a_1\in\mathfrak{a}\setminus\mathfrak{p_1},a_2\in\mathfrak{a}\setminus\mathfrak{p_2}$.  Then $a_1+a_1\in \mathfrak{a}$ but $a_1+a_2\not\in \mathfrak{p_1}$ because $a_1\not\in \mathfrak{p_1}$ and $a_2\in \mathfrak{p_1}$.  In the same way we see that $a_1+a_2\not\in \mathfrak{p_2}$, which gives a contradiction. (Note how in this part we haven't used that $\mathfrak{p_i}$ are prime ideals, only that they are ideals.)  Now suppose that $s>2$ and that $\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{p_i}\nsubseteq\cup_{j\neq i}\mathfrak{p_j}$ for all $i$ (so all ${\mathfrak{p}_i}'s$ are really needed).  Take for each $i$ an $a_i\in\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{p_i}\setminus\cup_{j\neq i}\mathfrak{p}_j.$ Then we get that $a=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_s\in \mathfrak{a}$.  We have $a_2\cdots a_s\not\in \mathfrak{a_1}$ (here we use that $\mathfrak{p}_1$ is a prime ideal) so $a\not\in \mathfrak{p}_1$ since $a_1\in \mathfrak{p}_1$.  If $i>1$ then $a_1\not\in \mathfrak{p}_i$ and $a_2\cdots a_s\in \mathfrak{p}_i$, so $a\not\in \mathfrak{p}_i$ which gives us a contradiction.

Here is a screenshot of the lemma and its proof:

Questions
I am using the above book since it has a easier intro to Grobner Bases compare with Chapter 9.6 of Dummit and Foote.  Also, the above proof, i have never seen it before from my self study on abstract algebra, and my primary text is Hungerford's undergraduate abstract algebra text.  When I try to do more problems relating to quotient rings for polynomials and ideals, I often encounter questions concerning multivariable cases.  I know that I need to eventually need to know Grobner bases, hence the questions which are confusing me are as follow:.
$(1)$ the induction the author is referring to, is it strong induction?  I know that the induction is over $s$, but what about over $i$?  (I don't have much experience doing proofs by strong induction.  I have mostly use weak induction for many proofs so far.)
$(2)$ When it says Then $a_1+a_1\in \mathfrak{a}$ but $a_1+a_2\not\in \mathfrak{p_1}$ because $a_1\not\in \mathfrak{p_1}$ and $a_2\in \mathfrak{p_1}$  Should $a_2\not\in \mathfrak{p_1}$ since if $a_1+a_2\not\in \mathfrak{p_1}$, and if $a_1=0$, then $a_2\not\in \mathfrak{p_1}$.
$(3)$  A related question from $(2)$ is what is the contradiction that the the author is referring to?
$(4)$ The portion where it reads:  Then we get that $a=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_s\in \mathfrak{a}$.  We have $a_2\cdots a_s\not\in \mathfrak{a_1}$ (here we use that $\mathfrak{a}_1$ is a prime ideal) so $a\not\in \mathfrak{p}_1$ since $a_1\in \mathfrak{p}_1$.  How does the author get from $a=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_s\in \mathfrak{a}$ implying $a_2\cdots a_s\not\in \mathfrak{a_1}$ which in turn implies $a_1\in \mathfrak{p}_1$?
$(5)$ The last part where it says If $i>1$ then $a_1\not\in \mathfrak{p}_i$ and $a_2\cdots a_s\in \mathfrak{p}_i$, is this referring to the contrapositive in the definition for prime ideal.  Because if so, should it not instead read: $a_1\not\in \mathfrak{p}_i$ and $a_2\cdots a_s\not\in \mathfrak{p}_i$, then $a\not \in \mathfrak{p}_i$.  But then, back to point $(4)$, how do we get from $a=a_1+a_2+,\cdots,a_s\in \mathfrak{a}$ to $a_2\cdots a_s\not\in \mathfrak{a_1}$? Also, what is the contradiction here?
Thank you in advance

(1) I'm unsure - there doesn't seem to be much induction going on here, though I could be incorrect.
(2) We chose $a_1$ and $a_2$ so that $a_1 \notin \mathfrak{p}_1$ and $a_2 \notin \mathfrak{p}_2$. We can however show that $a_1 \in \mathfrak{p}_2$.
The way we do this is we note that $a_1 \in \mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}_1 \cup \mathfrak{p}_2$ but $a_1 \notin \mathfrak{p}_1$. The only way $a_1$ can belong to the union but not $\mathfrak{p}_1$ is if it belongs to $\mathfrak{p}_2$. An identical argument shows that $a_2 \in \mathfrak{p}_1$.
Now we can prove that $a_1+a_2 \notin \mathfrak{p}_1$. We do this by using a mini proof by contradiction. Indeed, if $a_1+a_2\in\mathfrak{p}_1$, then (as $a_2 \in \mathfrak{p}_1$), we would have $a_1 \in \mathfrak{p}_1 $, which is a clear contradiction.
In an identical way, $a_1+a_2 \notin \mathfrak{p}_2$. So we see that $a_1+a_2$ is not in $\mathfrak{p}_1$ or $\mathfrak{p}_2$, so it is also not in the union.
(3) This is our contradiction. As we took $a_1$ and $a_2$ to be in $\mathfrak{a}$, their sum is also in $\mathfrak{a}$. But $\mathfrak{a}$ is contained in the union, so $a_1 +a_2$ must also be in the union, contradicting what we just showed above in (2).
(4) Your confusion likely comes from the fact that you are reading it as $a=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_s$, when really it says $a=a_1 +a_2\cdots a_s$ with the last factors multiplied, not added.
(5) If $i>1$, then $a_1 \notin \mathfrak{p}_i$. This comes from how we defined the $a_i$.
But what we do know is that $a_i$ is in $\mathfrak{p}_i$, again by construction. So (by the fact that ideals are closed under multiplication by elements of the ring) $a_2\cdots a_s$ is in $\mathfrak{p}_i$ (as the factor $a_i$ appears somewhere in this product).
This implies that $a=a_1+a_2\cdots a_s$ is not in $\mathfrak{p}_i$ (using a similar mini contradiction as in 2).
So $a$ is not in $\mathfrak{p}_1$, and it is not in $\mathfrak{p}_i$ for any $i>1$, so it is not in the union of all the prime ideals.
But this is a contradiction as we took $a\in \mathfrak{a}$, which is inside the union.

thank you so much for the clarification.  I have never seen the two lemma presented in a lot of abstract algebra text.  Thank you thank you.

@Seth This text is rather hard to follow. I would take the advice of the person on your last post and read another text.

thank you, I will keep Cox, Little, and O'Shea's text in mind also.  I thinkfrom this point on, things will be easier.  Everything else that will be covered has also been done by other sources.  I like the text i am using because it present things in bite size, like eating $m$ & $m$s, instead of eating one of those giant Easter Bunny chocolate all at once.
